# C++ hierarchy print exercise

Tags: c++, function, hierarchy

I'm learning C++ and I have a question about this exercise.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class B {
    public:
        int x;
        B(int z=1): x(z) {}
};

class D: public B {
    public:
        int y;
        D(int z=5): B(z-2), y(z) {}
};

void fun(B* a, int size) {
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) cout << (*(a+i)).x << " ";
}

int main(){
    fun(new D[4],4); cout << "**1\n";
    B* b = new D[4]; fun(b,4); cout << "**2\n";
    b[0] = D(6); b[1] = D(9); fun(b,4); cout << "**3\n";
    b = new B[4]; b[0] = D(6); b[1] = D(9);
    fun(b,4); cout << "**4\n";
}
```

It prints:

```
3 5 3 5 **1
3 5 3 5 **2
4 7 3 5 **3
4 7 1 1 **4
```

Why before the **1 and before **2, it prints 3 5 3 5? I thought 3 3 3 3.
Before the **3 I thought 5 7 3 3, and before **4 I thought 4 7 3 3.
Could you help me to better understand why it prints that way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such thing like C/C++. Your question clearly is C++, C doesn't have inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not treat arrays polymorphically. [[1](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/array-derived-vs-base.html)] [[2](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ARR39-CPP.+Do+not+treat+arrays+polymorphically)] You will get undefined behaviour, as you've observed. Luckily for you, you're just seeing wrong results, but there's a code snippet on that page that demonstrates a crash.

Comment: Thanks Chris Jester-Young and facthunter for your answers, now I've understood the first two lines of my main(). I've another question about the last part of my main(); for example when I see: 
    b[0] = D(6); b[1] = D(9);
what does it mean? I put the B object (contained in D) in b[0] and the D object in b[1], am I right? Then, with b[1] = D(9) I put the B object contained in D, in b[1] and the D object in b[2]?

Comment: @RobertoMilani No, when you do `b[0] = D(6)`, the assignment only copies the `B` portion of your `D` object (as if by calling `B::operator=(B const&)` with your `D` object as an argument), due to slicing. That _is_ well-defined, _if_ `b` is actually an array of `B` and not an array of `D`.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the first line of output 3 5 3 5 **1 from the line:

```
fun(new D[4],4); cout << "**1\n";
```

Please note that the method fun accepts B* as the parameter, which is the superclass of D. We are passing an array of D objects.

Furthermore, please note that we are using pointer arithmetics in the method fun when advancing to the next object in the array. B has one variable (x) and D as two (x and y) so B is half the size of object D. Our objects are D and not B (although they are sliced into B but they are stored as D in the contiguous memory - array), so we are advancing half way. As a result we are actually printing the value x (from B) and then the value of y (from D) and so on.